# Set NavigationBar background color on MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a problem changing background color of navigation bar on `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

I've tried this code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Configuration.Colors.navigationBarBackgroundColor
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.green
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 18)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white] as [String: AnyObject]

let composer = MFMessageComposeViewController() 

self?.present(composer, animated: true) {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}
```

And this is not working. The most strange thing is that it do work when I do the same for `MFMailComposeViewController`.

I also tried to change color directly on composer like this.

```
composer.navigationBar.tintColor = Configuration.Colors.navigationBarBackgroundColor
```

Comment: Please check this link [Link to set navigation on mail composer ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453933/ios-10-can-no-longer-set-barcolor-and-tint-on-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller)

Comment: Change in info.plist the row View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to NO

Comment: The property for setting the background colour is `composer.navigationBar.barTintColor` try it it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looks that i found workaround. Somehow setting `composer.navigationBar.barTintColor` and `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor` are not working.

The workaround is to use 
`UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(...)` and set UIImage with one color as background

Full working code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage.from(color: UIColor.green), for: .default)
let composer = MFMessageComposeViewController()       
self?.present(composer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to create `UIImage` with one color:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func from(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }
}
```